# Precolored nodes in register allocation - max one of each color?

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, register-allocation

I am looking into a topic on register allocation in compilers. A widely used algorithm for register allocation is iterative graph coloring by simplification. In the book *[Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052182060X)* by Andrew W. Appel, chapter 11 on register allocation states:

> Each node in the interference graph represents a temporary value.
>
> [...]
>
> Some temporaries are *precolored* - they represent machine registers. The front end generates these when interfacing to standard calling conventions across module boundaries, for example. For each actual register that is used for some specific purpose, such as the frame pointer, standard-argument-1-register, standard-argument-2-register, and so on, the `Codegen` or `Frame` module should use the particular temporary that is permanently bound to that register. **For any given color (that is, for any given machine register) there should be only one precolored node of that color.**

I don't completely understand the indicated line in the quote above. I can imagine situations where there are multiple temporaries that would be precolored with the same register. For example, the x86 `mul` instruction stores the result in the `EDX:EAX` register pair, but functions also return values in the `EAX` register. So I have different temporaries that have the same color. I would think that those different uses of `EAX` must be different nodes, or am I wrong?

*Could someone explain the highlighted sentence, maybe present some examples?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book, the idea is, you would have a single temporary EAX, which you use both with `mul` and for the return value.  When some value needs to be in a given register, you generate a move from the temporary containing that value to the temporary representing that register; similarly, once a value has arrived in a particular register (for example, a function has returned), you generate a move from the register's temporary to a temporary that will hold that value from then on.  See Figure 11.7 in the book.

Comment: So, to generalize: the same variable (virtual temporary or machine register) used for multiple different purposes in a method will only ever be represented by one single node in the interference graph?

Comment: I don't think that your generalization is valid.  It holds for the temporaries representing specific registers for precoloring purposes.